# Any good utilities for configuring network settings on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I don't really like the built-in tools for configuring the network settings on Windows XP. If for some reason I can't access the internet I never know where to look. Does anyone know of a good utility for fixing your internet or local network?

Comment: Did you ever try this answer?  If so, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party tool like that which comes with the network card (usually network cards have these tools).  I have found that these tools are even worse than the Windows XP ones.  I just got used to using XP methods, because they seem to work OK.  All in all, you will probably need a whole tool kit for dealing with your network, as this realm of fixes usually requires quite a bit of troubleshooting.  Just remember, you must change one variable at a time when you search for issues in a network.  Also, you will probably want to get used to basic command line work.  Here are some good resources for this:

http://www.grape-info.com/doc/win2000srv/network/netcommand.html

http://commandwindows.com/tcpiputil.htm